# active dropdown in selected row in angular6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have create a table in Angular 6.

What I want is whenever I click on edit button of a particular row, it should enable the roles dropdown for that particular role. As of now it is enabling it for all rows.

```
<th>
        <div id="thRole">
            <div *ngIf="!editRole else editRoleT">
                        {{user.description}}
                        <a (click)="EditRoles()">Edit</a>
            </div>
            <ng-template #editRoleT>
                    <select  name="rolelevel" id="drp" >
                            <option *ngFor="let role of roles " selected="role.id" value="role.id">{{role.description}}</option>
                        </select>
                        <a (click)="EditRoles()" >Add</a>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
       </th>
```

**EditRole()**

```
  EditRoles(){
     this.editRole=!this.editRole;
}
```

how can i do this ?

**Edit : All Tabel**

```
<nz-table
  #rowSelectionTable
  [nzData]="data"
  (nzCurrentPageDataChange)="currentPageDataChange($event)"
  (nzPageIndexChange)="refreshStatus()"
  (nzPageSizeChange)="refreshStatus()">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th ></th>
      <th style="text-align:right;font-family:  B Koodak;font-size: 16px">نام</th>
      <th  style="text-align:right;font-family: B Koodak;font-size: 16px">ایمیل</th> 
      <th  style="text-align:center;font-family: B Koodak;font-size: 16px">نقش</th> 
      <th  style="text-align:right;font-family: B Koodak;font-size: 16px">اکانت</th>
     <th  style="text-align:center;font-family:B Koodak;font-size: 16px">عملیات</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr *ngFor="let user of data | searchuser: nameSearch: emailSearch: roleSearch">
      <td >
         <i nz-icon (click)="infoUser(user.id)" style="cursor:pointer;" type="info-circle" theme="outline"></i>
        </td> 
      <td  style="text-align:right;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-weight: 500;font-size: 13px">{{user.desplayName}}</td>
      <td  style="text-align:right;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-weight: 500;font-size: 13px">{{user.email}}</td> 
      <th  style="text-align:right;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-weight: 500;font-size: 13px;width: 239px;">
        <div id="thRole">
            <div *ngIf="!editRole else editRoleT">
                        {{user.description}}
                        <a (click)="EditRoles()" style="color:#ffaa2a;float: left;text-decoration: blue;">ویرایش</a>
            </div>
            <ng-template #editRoleT>
                    <select  name="rolelevel" id="drp" >
                            <option *ngFor="let role of roles " selected="role.id" value="role.id">{{role.description}}</option>
                        </select>
                        <a (click)="EditRoles()" style="padding-top: 8px;color:#055f09;float: left;text-decoration: blue;">ثبت</a>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
       </th> 
      <th style="text-align:center;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-weight: 500;font-size: 13px">
            <p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="user.isActive" (click)="changeActive(user.id)"></p-inputSwitch>
      <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: 500;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-size: 13px">
         <a id="noconfirm">حذف</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</nz-table>
```

this is all table code .

Comment: Share your entire table code.

Comment: @SunilSingh i edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handles your scenario however the simplest way to have to store the row index and match with each row.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of data; let rowIndex of index | searchuser: nameSearch: emailSearch: roleSearch">
      <td >
         <i nz-icon (click)="infoUser(user.id); seletedRowIndex = rowIndex" style="cursor:pointer;" type="info-circle" theme="outline"></i>
        </td> 
      <td  style="text-align:right;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-weight: 500;font-size: 13px">{{user.desplayName}}</td>
      <td  style="text-align:right;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-weight: 500;font-size: 13px">{{user.email}}</td> 
      <th  style="text-align:right;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-weight: 500;font-size: 13px;width: 239px;">
        <div id="thRole">
            <div *ngIf="!(seletedRowIndex === rowIndex) else editRoleT">
                        {{user.description}}
                        <a (click)="EditRoles()" style="color:#ffaa2a;float: left;text-decoration: blue;">ویرایش</a>
            </div>
            <ng-template #editRoleT>
                    <select  name="rolelevel" id="drp" >
                            <option *ngFor="let role of roles " selected="role.id" value="role.id">{{role.description}}</option>
                        </select>
                        <a (click)="seletedRowIndex = rowIndex" style="padding-top: 8px;color:#055f09;float: left;text-decoration: blue;">ثبت</a>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
       </th> 
      <th style="text-align:center;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-weight: 500;font-size: 13px">
            <p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="user.isActive" (click)="changeActive(user.id)"></p-inputSwitch>
      <th style="text-align:center;font-weight: 500;font-family: Iranian Sans;font-size: 13px">
         <a id="noconfirm">حذف</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
```

> Note : the code is written directly on Stackoverflow editor so there could be typo or syntactical error. Please correct yourself.

Comment: Added these code `(click)="infoUser(user.id); seletedRowIndex = rowIndex" `

Comment: Please create stackblitz demo.

Comment: i can not using the stackblitz .  my problem with your code is this : i read agin your code and reused it . it half work , mean , when i click the edit , it active dropdown for selected row and when i click on the update button it update but it not hide the dropdown .

Comment: On update you can use `seletedRowIndex = -1`. It should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code. Add an editRole variable to the user object and check if that specific users editRole has been changed. Also replace ng-template with div.

```
<div id="thRole">
  <div *ngIf="!user.editRole">
    {{user.description}}
    <a (click)="EditRoles(user)">Edit</a>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="user.editRole">
    <select name=" rolelevel" id="drp">
      <option *ngFor="let role of roles " selected="role.id" value="role.id">{{role.description}}</option>
    </select>
    <a (click)="EditRoles(user)">Add</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now in Edit Roles Function use a similar approach

```
EditRoles(user){
     // Find the user from data object and invert editRole
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In *your-component.component.html*

use [(ngModel)] to bind selected roleId.

```
<select  name="rolelevel" id="drp" [(ngModel)]="selectedRoleId">
  <option *ngFor="let role of roles " [value]="role.id">{{ role.description }}
  </option>
</select>
```

In *your-component.component.ts*

```
selectedRoleId;
```

> Don't forget to import FormsModule in your feature module.

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   ...
   FormsModule,
   ...
  ]
})
export class YourModule {}
```

Comment: Did you removed. `selected="role.id"` from `<option *ngFor="let role of roles " selected="role.id" value="role.id">{{role.description}}</option>`

Paste this.

`<option *ngFor="let role of roles "  [value]="role.id">{{role.description}}</option>`

Comment: In that case use editRole as object and handle it as.
!editRole[user.id]

`editRole : any = {};`;

And in EditRoles function
make 
`EditRoles(userId) {
    if(!this.editRole[userId]) {
    this.editRole[userId] = true;
  } else {
    this.editRole[userId] = !this.editRole[userId];
  } 
 }`